# Query times out when using the marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Query seems to error / times out in automation studio and there are no errors outputted.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT [Email Address],[UserID] 
FROM [Students - Test]
JOIN (SELECT user_id 
      FROM Saved_Searches 
      WHERE period = 7 or period = 1) test ON test.user_id = UserID
```

Is there a way to run this directly on the system and is there a way to index the field period?

Answer (score 1):

First, if the query times out, you'll get an error email from Automation Studio, if you have the Runtime Error email address filled in:

[image: Automation Studio notifications]

The default query timeout period in the ExactTarget/SFMC platform is **30** minutes.  If you violate a key or try to insert null into a non-nullable column, then your query will also fail.  In my experience, those are the three main causes for query failures.

There is no console to debug query errors.  You'll need to [contact SF support](http://www.exacttarget.com/services/technical-support).  They can tell you the reason the query failed.  Generally, they suggest breaking down your query into multiple queries or smaller data sets if you're running up against the 30 minute timeout period.  Some ET/SFMC Partners have can also provide you with details about query failures.

Indexes can be added behind the scenes, but only in extraordinary circumstances.  Those usually involve a services engagement.  It's best to use define and utilize primary keys in your related data extension joins.

I'd re-write your query like this:

```
SELECT 
    s.[Email Address]
    , s.[UserID] 
FROM [Students - Test] s
INNER JOIN saved_searches ss on (
    ss.user_id = s.UserID and ss.period in (1,7)
)
```

Comment: Why are you rewriting the query? Is there a performance impact?

Comment: Adams Query usually performs faster because of no double select Statement and using the in function